# Make the width of cells in the second table-row equal to the width of cells in first table-row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using the [CSS `display` property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) with `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` values to layout my document in the form of a table.

Normally (as you can see in the code) the size of the cells in the table is related to the content that contain (until we provide hard-coded dimension values.

**But I want the `table-cell`s in the second (and so on) `table-row` to have the same width as the corresponding `table-cell` from the first `table-row`.** So the width of the 1st `table-cell` in the second row is the same as the width of the 1st `table-cell` in the first `table-row`. Is it possible?

I want to do this without having to add `pixel` `margin` or `padding` etc. properties in the second and subsequent `table-row`s. I just want it to get the `width` of the cell above it.

**So in the end, the width of a column will be equal to that of the widest cell in the column.**

How can I do that?

**[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tywswm8w/)** In the code, the three rows have different colors.

CODE:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div style="background-color:#d9a4f4; display:table-row;">
        <label style="display:table-cell; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">Inferrable</label>
        <label style="display:table-cell; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">Not inferrable</label>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#7cbfdd; display:table-row;">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_group1" value="0" style="display:table-cell;">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_group1" value="0" style="display:table-cell;">
        <label style="display:table-cell;">I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. </label>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#e8c277; display:table-row;">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_group2" value="0" style="display:table-cell;">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_group2" value="1" style="display:table-cell;">
        <label style="display:table-cell;">I am the label for the second group of radio buttons. I am the label for the second group of radio buttons. I am the label for the second group of radio buttons. </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhhh! don't do that. if you want them to match exactly be explicit or use a table layout (*cough*)

Comment: Don't use inline styles, define your styles in a separate CSS file.

Comment: you have incorrect number of cells in each row - they should match if you want them to be equal as display-table doesn't have things like colspan.  As your data looks as if it can be classed as tabular, you should just use a proper table with `th` and `scope`s set for the first row

Comment: @DanielA.White Html-table is ruled out I can't use that. The problem with explicit `width` is that in the first row, sometimes it will have  words as small as 'Yes` and `No` as labels, and sometimes `inferrable` and `Not inferrable`. So e.g. if I make it `width:150px` considering `Not Inferrable`, it will be too wide for the word `No`

Comment: @Pete If I add a third `table-cell` in the first `table-row` will it solve the problem?

Comment: @Dan I have a few reasons to use inline styles for the time being, however I understand the importance of using separate style-sheets. I will later convert them to stylesheets.

Comment: it should do although I also wouldn't use the table-cell style directly on the inputs - perhaps wrap them in a span with display table-cell style attached to it - http://jsfiddle.net/coyvacm5/

Comment: @Pete Thank you. Follow-up question: Why not use style directly on the inputs?

Comment: Radio buttons have limited styles you can apply to them so you will have various results depending on which browser you are using

Comment: @Pete Thank you. Your solution is the most appropriate answer, so if you can write it as an answer, I will accept it. It will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a cell to your first row and then wrap your inputs in a span:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div style="background-color:#d9a4f4; display:table-row;">
        <label style="display:table-cell; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">Inferrable</label>
        <label style="display:table-cell; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">Not inferrable</label> 
        <span style="display:table-cell;"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#7cbfdd; display:table-row;">
        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;"><input type="radio" name="radio_group1" value="0" style="display:table-cell;"></span>
        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;"><input type="radio" name="radio_group1" value="0" style="display:table-cell;"></span>
        <label style="display:table-cell;">I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons. I am the label for the first group of radio buttons.</label>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#e8c277; display:table-row;">
        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;"><input type="radio" name="radio_group2" value="0" style="display:table-cell;"></span>
        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;"><input type="radio" name="radio_group2" value="1" style="display:table-cell;"></span>
        <label style="display:table-cell;">I am the label for the second group of radio buttons. I am the label for the second group of radio buttons. I am the label for the second group of radio buttons.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should be able to achieve what you want - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/coyvacm5/)

[Titles on one line instead of wrapping](http://jsfiddle.net/coyvacm5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

All the `DIV`, `label` and `input` elements are completely separate and even if they're set to `display: table-cell` they have no internal relationship and no knowledge about each others dimensions.

You will have to define their width explicitly to have their widths match. (Then you essentially don't need the `display`-properties for them any more).

Here's a **jsfiddle demo with modifications to your code**:

http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/ga1hzrLd/

This has a suggestion for a modified structure you could use to align your elements without thinking about them in a table-like layout:

Comment: No no no, What I am looking for is that the radio buttons should come under the first two cells of the first row (the `inferrable` and `Not inferrable` labels).

Comment: The problem with explicit width is that in the first row, sometimes it will have words as small as `Yes` and `No` as `label`s, and sometimes long words like `inferrable` and `Not inferrable`. So e.g. if I make it `width:150px` considering `Not Inferrable`, it will be too wide for the word `No`