# CSS: Why is this label taking up all the available space

Tags: html, css, label

The given example is probably a bit bigger than required but I could not figure out in hours where the problem lies, so I am posting it. You just have to look into the `label` `#problematic` and around it (**Line number 9 in the JSFiddle**).

**The problem with it is that it takes up all the space left by the adjacent `label`. The question is why? And what to do about it?**

[I had worked out this example](http://jsfiddle.net/coyvacm5/1/) (with the help of some [SO community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528447/make-the-width-of-cells-in-the-second-table-row-equal-to-the-width-of-cells-in-f)) to make the layout before incorporating the complex content. It works perfectly in the example. But it behaves weirdly in my code.

**[Here is the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/k8qa2Le6/)**

CODE:-

```
<form action="http://localhost/moodle/mod/quiz/processattempt.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" id="responseform">
    <div>
        <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->

        <div style="display:table;">
            <div style="display:table-row; background-color:#e8c277;">
                <label id="problematic" style="display:table-cell; padding:10px; border-width:1px;border-color:blue;border-style:solid;">True</label>
                <label style="display:table-cell; padding:10px;border-width:1px;border-color:red;border-style:solid;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">False</span></label>
                <span style="display:table-cell;"></span>
            </div>
        <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
        <div class="que multichoice deferredfeedback notyetanswered" id="q13">
            <div>
                <div class="formulation">
                    <h4 class="accesshide">Question text</h4>
                    <input type="hidden" name="q36:13_:sequencecheck" value="1" />
                    <div class="ablock" style="display:table-row;">
                        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;">
                            <input type="radio" name="q36:13_answer" value="0" id="q36:13_answer0" /> 
                        </span>
                        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;">
                            <input type="radio" name="q36:13_answer" value="1" id="q36:13_answer1" /> 
                        </span>
                        <label class="qtext" style="display:table-cell;">No individual country produces more than one-fourth of the world's sugar.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="que multichoice deferredfeedback notyetanswered" id="q14">
            <div>
                <div class="formulation">
                    <h4 class="accesshide">Question text</h4>
                    <input type="hidden" name="q36:14_:sequencecheck" value="1" />
                    <div class="ablock" style="display:table-row;">
                        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;">
                            <input type="radio" name="q36:14_answer" value="0" id="q36:14_answer0" /> 
                        </span>
                        <span style="display:table-cell; text-align:center;">
                            <input type="radio" name="q36:14_answer" value="1" id="q36:14_answer1" /> 
                        </span>
                        <label class="qtext" style="display:table-cell;">If Brazil produces less than 20% of the world's supply of any commodity listed in the table, Brazil is not the world's top exporter of than commodity.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
        </div>
        <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
        <div class="submitbtns">
            <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's the way `table-cell` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have divs wrapping your table rows/cells. There were divs wrapping your second and third rows, causing them to be treated as if they were all in the first column.

See the fiddle below for an example of a working layout. Note: I deleted *a lot* of your divs. Your table structure has to be `table`:`table-row`:`table-cell` with no other divs wrapping the rows or cells. Removing the excess divs restored the proper layout.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tehc79xa/)</kbd>

Comment: Add `width: 100%` to your span.

Comment: In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coyvacm5/1/), I did not set the other `label`'s and `span`'s width explicitly either, the labels just got the `width` according to their contents implicitly, and the `span` (since it's empty) took up the remaining space. But in this piece of code, why isn't the rest of the space being taken up by the `span`?

Comment: That disturbs the elements under it.

Comment: Your elements underneath it are not in the right columns. They are all in the first column. That is why "True" was stretched as much as it was. Move them to the proper columns and the problem should go away.

Comment: Can you edit the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8qa2Le6/) a bit? Because I could not figure out what's wrong with them?

Comment: Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tehc79xa/. Note: I deleted a lot of divs. Your table structure has to be `table`:`tr`:`td` with no other divs wrapping the rows or cells. Removing the wrapping divs restored the proper layout.

Comment: Oh! Is there a way to keep those `div`s because they are there. I can't get rid of them.

Comment: Yes you can keep them, but you will have to make large changes to your layout. Put the `display: table-row` on the first div (the one that is the direct child of the `display: table` div) and put `display:table-cell` on its direct childs. If you just do that now, you will not get the layout that you are expecting; you'll have to rearrange them in order to get the correct table layout. Just follow the simple guideline that a table can only have table row children and table rows can only have table cell children, which can have anything as children.

Comment: I will just try it. Thank you so very much.